# Rails / SCSS difference between @include and *= require?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone explain the difference between the `*= require` comments:

```
/*
 *= require foo
 */
```

and `@include` statements:

```
@include "bar";
```

In `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` in a Rails app?

Answer (score 1):

`@include` is a SASS statement to include a SASS mixin into your current CSS scope, [documented here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#including_a_mixin).

`*= require` is a Sprockets declaration to the Sprocket compiler to pull the contents of the named file into that location in the resulting CSS, [documented here](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#the-require-directive).